# nfs4_setfacl - users able to create files but not able to create directories

Tags: linux, nfs, file-sharing, nfsclient

I have set the following permission using `nfs4_sefacl`

```
$ sudo nfs4_setfacl -a A:g:foo-group@mydomain.com:rwx /mnt/shared

$ sudo nfs4_getfacl /mnt/shared

# file: /mnt/shared
A:g:foo-group@mydomain.com:rwx
A::OWNER@:rwaDxtTnNcCy
A:g:GROUP@:rwaDxtTnNcy
A::EVERYONE@:rxtncy
```

Interestingly, the users of `foo-group` are able to create only files under `/mnt/shared`, but they are unable to create any directories under the folder.

I am new to nfs4_setfacl, may I know what am I missing?
The volume is mounted as NFS4 volume correctly.

Answer (score 0):

The [permissions](https://linux.die.net/man/5/nfs4_acl) for the `foo-group` group need to be inherited. ACE (entry) for `foo-group` doesn't have the `d` and `f` flags.

Granted, the other ACEs also don't have these flags, but the NFS' [file creation rules](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc5661#section-6.4.3) cover that case. On Linux, file creation would usually [set the mode and not the ACL](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc5661#section-6.4.1.1), and the mode would have reasonable behavior for the 3 regular principals - owner, group, and other.